# How to check if a data is a map (key-value pairs)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Before processing data (a DataSnapshot coming from Firebase), I need to check if data returned are well formated as a Map before deserializing through an Interface.

After looking the net, I found this example coded with Kotlin:

```
override fun deserialize(input: DataSnapshot): StockPrice {
    val data = input.value
    return if (data is Map<*, *>) {
        StockPrice(
            input.key!!,
            (data["price"] as Number).toFloat(),
            Date(data["time"] as Long),
            true
        )
    }
    else {
        throw Deserializer.DeserializerException("input.value wasn't a Map")
    }
}
```

How to implement such a behaviour in Android Studio & Java ?

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
      StockPrice deserialize(DataSnapshot input){

                  if (input instanceof Map<>)
                   {
                // todo if input is a map<>
                   } else { 
                 //throw error or send message to user
            throw Deserializer.serializeException(" that is not a 
               map")
             }
  }
```

Hope this will help you